# Play Framework website session does not remember form input from previous page

Tags: html, playframework

I have a Play framework project that asks for information to be submitted on four pages (i.e., enter information on page 1, click "go to page 2" and continue) and on my local Macbook Pro when I run this application (`play run`) everything runs perfectly. All the information is saved step by step (I save it using `session`), so when I go to page 2 and look at HTML like the following:

`<input type="hidden" name="myFirstField" value="WhatIwroteOnPage1">`

As you can see the value from page 1 is saved on page 2 in the source.

Here is my problem ...

I took this project and `scp -r`'d it onto a server running CentOS with OpenJDK and the same version of Play (2.1.1) (note my Mac has Java (SE)). However now, for some reason the session isn't saved and in the same situation as before I see the following:

`<input type="hidden" name="myFirstField" value="">`

So for some reason, none of my information is saved! The **only** changes I made were:

- Changed the database password (the db name and username are the same)

That's it. Other than that the only differences are that I:

- Use `play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true start` instead of `play run` (but the behaviour is the same with `play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true run`)
- The different Java versions

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? Any help is greatly appreciated, this project is quite important and I'm completely lost. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. Put my Play project (the folder I'm in when I run `play start`) into my downloaded Play directory (/.../play-2.1.1/)